# JBoss PHP installation on Windows

Tags: php, windows, jboss

Has anyone used JBoss with PHP on windows ?
I googled that think, in order to make a solution, I downloaded the latest JBoss web ( http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/downloads/jboss-web-2-1-4) and the php zip for JBoss and windows, but all seem to fail in php5servlet.dll, which is outdated to 2006!
I don't understand, it is 2006 but has over 4000 downloads instead the other versions.
What version of JBoss-web, php, mysql can work with that php5servlet (http://labs.jboss.com/file-access/default/members/jbossweb/freezone/dist/1.0.0.GA/php5servlet-windows-i586-SP1.zip) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the instructions and the link to the php5servlet.dll at the following address helped me a lot: http://community.jboss.org/thread/146107?tstart=1

Comment: perhaps rather old, I went with Oracle's Glassfish. And Quercus. Very good result